# My ListView items doesn't change color when setenabled false

Tags: android, android-layout

I got this example from hear, but it doesn't work fine. My items were disabled but the color of my items (black) still the same.

Thanks

### The example

- Create a ListView
- Enable filtering for the text view
- Make sure that the first item is disabled
- Filter the view so that the first item is not shown

If you do this you can see that the new first item is disabled.

So how do I best work around this?

Below is the smallest possible sample code that demonstrates the problem, just filter for something other than the first three items.

**CustomListActivity.java**

```
package com.example.bug;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class CustomListActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String items[] = new String[100];

        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
            items[i] = "Item " + (i+1);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, items) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setEnabled(isEnabled(position));
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                return position >= 3;
            }
        });

        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" package="com.example.bug">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="CustomListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**res/color/list_item_colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#777" />
    <item android:color="#fff" />
</selector>
```

**res/layout/list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_colors" />
```

Comment: Did u try changing the color in the getView|() method itself instead of XML ?

Comment: how can i do this?
i can't do  view.setColor()

Comment: You want to set color to entire view of list item ?Did you try view.setBackgroundColor(color) ?

Comment: great. you can share the solution

Comment: it means that the question you asked was a really basic one and you needed to search more before asking the question.The rules of this forum are really strict.Please read the FAQ and rules section of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can try thus. Such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#777" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="#555" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="#fff"/>

</selector>
```